# Ruby on Rails: How do you combine two arrays and have the "where" method available?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For example, I'd like to combine two arrays and add the where clause like so:

(Recipe.current + Recipe.previous).where(:name => "ABC")

I know that you can combine it into one (Recipe.where("current is true or previous is true")), but I have a few complex queries that forces me to combine the arrays in the manner above.

Is it possible?

Comment: Are `current`and `previous` scopes? I thought you could just chain scopes.

Comment: Do you want the resulting array to contain the arrays combined, or a union or the arrays? (Would make a bit of a difference in the answer.)

Comment: I used "current" and "previous" to distinguish the different collections. Sorry for the confusion. I know you can chain scopes, but I'm looking to combine two arrays first, and then be able to use the "where" method afterward.

Comment: The `where` method is only available for relations, not for arrays, which makes sense because an array is a result of a database query, whereas a relation is something you use to build the query. If you describe the complex queries I'm sure it's possible to express them as relations.

Comment: Yes, I want the resulting array to contain the two arrays combined.

Comment: I tried doing something like so: (Recipe.current.merge(Recipe.previous)).where(:name => "ABC"), but while the "where" method works, the arrays don't merge (it only includes the Recipe.previous).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on how many database queries you want to run to get the information.

If it's okay to have 2 database queries, you might do something like this:

```
rel     = Recipe.where(:name => "ABC")
recipes = rel.current | rel.previous
```

If you want to have it all in 1 database query, you have to use an `OR` clause in your relation, unless you want to go beyond the regular ActiveRecord methods and use Arel or one of the query generation gems.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much Cypher :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to make a complex single SQL query in Rails to archive your goals?
If you can do that in plain SQL queries, it's generally possible in Rails.

Building a customized SQL query string might be another solution.

Another way is to combine these arrays and use Ruby's "reject!" to delete elements that doesn't match your pattern, there might be some performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

Your model's `.current` and `.previous` seems like a scope returning a `ActiveRecord::Relation` object. For these objects the method `.where` is available, but when you combine these objects its returning an Array. Arrays does not have the `.where`. So you have to pass that query before th combination or clean the queries mess. If you choose the second i'd highly recommend the [Squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) gem.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for the recommendation Alexandre